# Can I cancel the last ship command in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

This one happens a lot - I give a command to the wrong ship, can I cancel the command and restore the last set of commands to the current ship?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Too bad, seems like a missing feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cancel the current command and all the commands in the queue by clicking on the "stop" button in the ship info but unfortunately, there is no way to restore the last set of commands.

[image: Stop ship]

Comment: When you say "you can cancel the current command", you mean that you can cancel *all* of the current command*s*?

Comment: @DCShannon I updated my answer